# Subclipse: What is the green bar icon on the top right for?

Tags: eclipse, icons, subclipse

do you know the meaning behind the green bar icon (5th icon in the image behind the link)? I think it is in dependence with the eclipse plugin subclipse. Maybe some conflicts between versions? And what is to do, to get it away?

[image-link with green bar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiXOZ.png)

I'm sorry guys, I'm not allowed to post images directly, because I have not enough reputation points. But i would be happy, if you can help me anyhow :)

Comment: There is a post of the subclipse forum that says the overlays are described on the `Preferences > Team > SVN > Label Decorations` page

Comment: Thank you for your fast anwser. I checked this already, but there are just the basic icons described. [Here a screenshot of my preferences](http://i.imgur.com/hlutuNN.png). As you can see, there is the green bar icon not described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While trying to find out myself, I saw Mark Phippard's comment about the General page for decorations. I went to `Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations` and began disabling decorations until the green bar went away.

Turns out it was `Decorate Classes with Test Case` that caused the green bar, which can be unchecked to disable it. Searching for that, I found MoreUnit to be responsible: http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/

Looks like "MoreUnit decorates files which have a test case". I'm guessing it does so by seeing if there is a class starting with the same name and ending in "Test" or whatever the MoreUnit config might include.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you for telling us how you found it out and what it was :)

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse, and all team providers in general, only decorate the bottom-right corner.  I do not know what that is in the top-right but it does not come from Subclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark! When its true, it can not be subclipse. Does anyone else know, what it could be? The files which are marked with a green bar have the only logical connection with version problems (in my mind). The Eclipse Version is Juno, installed pulgins are EGit (not used here), FindBugs, Checkstyle, MyLyn WikiText, PTI - PHP Tool Integration and Subclipse. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Open Preferences and type "Decor" in the search field. This will show all preference panes for Decorations.  The General page tells you all of the decorations that are enabled, so that might narrow it down.  You might also find a pref page for another plugin.